# presentViewController from UINavigationController's childViewController (Animation issue)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, ios7

I am having some weird animation issues.
I called `presentViewController` with animation set to `YES` but the animation is not present when the view controller is being presented. And the weirdest thing is all animations throughout the app are gone!

So basically my setup is like this

`UINavigationController` has child view controller - `childVC`

I have `childViewController` to call `presentViewController` - `presentVC`
and have a delegate callback method for `childViewController` to dismiss `presentVC`.

One interesting thing I found is this

```
[childVC presentViewController: presentVC];
NSLog(@"%@", [presentVC presentingViewController]); <- this prints UINavigationController!
```

Shouldn't it prints `childVC`? I am really confused with why it prints the `parentController` of the `childVC` instead.

I have been stuck on this weird animation issue for a very long time. I wonder if the `presentingViewController` being the `UINavigationController` have something to do with it?

Thoughts?

/* edited */
another thing I forgot to mention is that, childVC is part of the subclass of ECSlidingViewController, (meaning it childVC is one of the topViewController, underleftViewController or underRightViewController) if that makes any difference.

Comment: do you write like that? [self presentViewController:presentVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Are you triggering some animations in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Rafael: Yes. Inside ChildVC class, I called  [self presentViewController:presentVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Sulthan: nope, no other animations are triggered in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad.