# presentViewController method giving animateTransition wrong FromViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm currently working on a custom `ViewController` that manages at least one and up to five `ViewController`. They are aligned in a "plus", where the mandatory view controller is the center `ViewController`, and the other four can go on any side of the centre `ViewController`. The class is `TDSlidingViewController` in this project.

The problem I'm running into regards what view controllers are being passed into animateTransition. The following is the code preparing to transition (it's inside `TDSlidingViewController`.m):

```
    targetViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    targetViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationNone;

    if (_currentViewController == [self.slidingControllerDatasource viewControllerForLocation:SlidingViewCenter]) {
        [_currentViewController presentViewController:targetViewController animated:YES completion:^(void) {
            NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@", self.childViewControllers, self.view.subviews, self.currentViewController.childViewControllers);
            [self.currentViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:[self gestureRecognizersForSlidingViewLocation:self.currentLocation][0]];
        }];
     } else {
        [[self.slidingControllerDatasource viewControllerForLocation:self.previousLocation] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
     }
```

The following code runs in animateTransition:

```
UIView *container = transitionContext.containerView;

UIViewController *currentViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *targetViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

NSLog(@"%@", [currentViewController class]);
```

What caught my attention is that NSLog is not printing the `_currentViewController`, but the container for the `SlidingViewController`, `TDMainViewController`; the transition removes the entire stack of `ViewController` and displays one `ViewController`.

I believe it is causing `[[self.slidingControllerDatasource viewControllerForLocation:self.previousLocation] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];` to crash with the following output (`TDEditorViewController` is the controller that was displayed from the transition initially):

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'presentedViewController for controller is itself on dismiss for: <`TDEditorViewController`: 0x8d69250>'
```

I have searched and searched, and the only link I can find that is similar is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931547/presentviewcontroller-from-uinavigationcontrollers-childviewcontroller-animati), which has not been answered.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I researched a little bit more, and came to the conclusion that the flaw was in the design. Instead of trying to present view controllers inside of a container view, I simply passed the gestures around so it knows when to move back to the center. The `StackViewController` that was originally going to be the container view, now facilitates the transitions from the background, holding the gesture recognizers, managing animations and passing around data. All that's changed is it's not displayed.